# Why NetLogo runs different with the same syntax and logic in two time periods

Tags: netlogo

everyone! I am struggling with NetLogo procedures. The code is seemingly correct, but the model cannot run. I hope anyone can help me with this. 
I designed this model like:

Period1: day > 0 and day < 30 and time > 1, the turtles go to some patches(patch 1, patch 2, patch 3,...) and stop according to the rules, each patch has the maximum storage of turtles, if the patch reaches its maximum storage, ask all the turtles on this patch die.

Period2: if day >= 31 and day < 60 and time > 1, ask the newly create turtles go to the same patches in Period1, and each patch has the different maximum storage, if the patch reaches its maximum storage, ask all the turtles on this patch die.

The logic and syntax are the same in Period1 and Period2, the only difference is the parameters' value. However, Period1 works, Period2 doesn't work. I mean in the Period1 turtles can go to the patches and die correctly; turtles even cannot move and nothing happened in Period2 but the ticks still run and without any error reminder. Why did this happen? Could anyone give me some suggestions?

The code is as below:

```
globals [time day randomSeedVar]
breed [RiverVolumes RiverVolume]                        ;; ceate a breed to represent river volumes
breed [WaterVolumes WaterVolume]              ;; ceate a breed to represent irrigation volumes
breed [Crops Crop]
patches-own[CurrentStorage QgateMaxR QgateMaxR1 QgateMaxL QgateMaxL1]

to setup
  clear-all
  import-pcolors "patches.png"
  ifelse Seed?
  [
    random-seed RandomSeed
  ]
  [
    set randomSeedVar (random 2147483646)
    random-seed randomSeedVar
  ]
  set-default-shape RiverVolumes "default"
  set-default-shape WaterVolumes "drop"
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  set time ticks mod 24                                                                  ;; there are 24 ticks per day, one tick is equal to 1 hour
  set day floor (ticks / 24) + 1
  tick
  RiverInflow
  set-label
 if day > 0 and day < 30 and time > 1
  [
    FirstIrrigation
    RCropGrowth-1
    LCropGrowth-1
    DeathOfFirstWaterVolumes
    set-label
  ]

  if day = 30
  [
    ask patches with [pcolor = 64.2]
    [
      set CurrentStorage 0
    ]
  ]

  if day > 30 and day < 60 and time > 1
  [
    SecondIrrigation
    RCropGrowth-2
    LCropGrowth-2
    DeathOfSecondWaterVolumes
    set-label
  ]
end

to RiverInflow
  ask RiverVolumes [fd 1]
  create-RiverVolumes 1000
  [
    setxy 18 1
    set color blue - 2                                                              ;; set color of turtle to dark blue
    set size 0.5                                                                    ;; set size of turtle to 0.5
    set heading 180
  ]
end

to FirstIrrigation                                                                             ;; means flow the water to canals
  ifelse [CurrentStorage] of patch 35 1 < FirstStorage
  [
    move-to-right-canal1-1
    RGateCapacity-1
    RGateFlow1-1
    RFieldStorage-1
    RFieldStorageOverFlow-1
  ]
  [
    ifelse [CurrentStorage] of patch 1 1 < FirstStorage
    [
      move-to-left-canal1-1
      LGateCapacity-1
      LGateFlow1-1
      LFieldStorage-1
      LFieldStorageOverFlow-1
    ]
    [
       ask patches with [pycor = 0]
       [
         if any? RiverVolumes-here
         [
           ask RiverVolumes [die]
         ]

       ]
     ]
   ]
end

to move-to-right-canal1-1
  ask patches with [pcolor = 95.1]
  [
    if pxcor = 18 and pycor = 0
    [
      ask n-of QgateMaxFixed1 RiverVolumes-here
      [
        lt 90
        fd 1
      ]
    ]
  ]
end

to RGateCapacity-1
  ask patches with [pcolor = 48.8]                                                      ;; gates at the right side of the river
  [
    ifelse pxcor = 19
    [
      set QgateMaxR1 QgateMaxFixed1                                                     ;; set the capacity of the first right gate is QgateMaxFixed1
    ]
    [
      set QgateMaxR QgateMaxFixed
    ]
  ]
end

to RGateFlow1-1
  ask patches with [pcolor = 48.8 and pycor = 0]                               ;; gates at the right side of the river
  [
    ifelse pxcor = 19
    [
      ask n-of QgateMaxFixed1 RiverVolumes-here [fd 1]
    ]
    [
      ifelse CurrentStorage < FirstStorage
      [
        ifelse (count RiverVolumes-here - QgateMaxR) > 0
        [
          ask n-of QgateMaxFixed RiverVolumes-here [lt 90]
        ]
        [
          ask n-of (count RiverVolumes-here) RiverVolumes-here [lt 90]
        ]
      ]
      [
      ]
    ]
  ]
end

to RFieldStorage-1
  ask patches with [pcolor = 64.2]                                     ;; ask the fields at the right side of the river
  [
    set CurrentStorage (CurrentStorage + count RiverVolumes-here)
    sprout-WaterVolumes (count RiverVolumes-here)
    ask WaterVolumes-here
    [
      set color 97
      set size 0.8
      set heading 0
    ]
    ask RiverVolumes-here [die]
  ]
end

to RFieldStorageOverFlow-1
  ask patches with [pcolor = 64.2]
  [
    if CurrentStorage > FirstStorage
    [
      ask n-of (CurrentStorage - FirstStorage) WaterVolumes-here [die]
      set CurrentStorage FirstStorage
    ]
  ]
end

to move-to-left-canal1-1
  ask patches with [pcolor = 95.1]
  [
    if pxcor = 18 and pycor = 0
    [
        ask n-of QgateMaxFixed1 RiverVolumes-here
        [
          rt 90
          fd 1
        ]
    ]
  ]
end

to LGateCapacity-1
  ask patches with [ pcolor = 47.4]                                                     ;; gates at the left side of the river
  [
    ifelse pxcor = 17
    [
      set QgateMaxL1 QgateMaxFixed1                                                     ;; set the capacity of the first right gate is QgateMaxFixed1
    ]
    [
      set QgateMaxL QgateMaxFixed
    ]
  ]
end

to LGateFlow1-1
  ask patches with [pcolor = 47.4 and pycor = 0]                               ;; gates at the left side of the river
  [
    ifelse pxcor = 17
    [
      ask n-of QgateMaxFixed1 RiverVolumes-here [fd 1]
    ]
    [
      ifelse CurrentStorage < FirstStorage
      [
        ifelse (count RiverVolumes-here - QgateMaxL) > 0
        [
          ask n-of QgateMaxFixed RiverVolumes-here [rt 90]
        ]
        [
          ask n-of (count RiverVolumes-here) RiverVolumes-here [rt 90]
        ]
      ]
      [
      ]
    ]
  ]
end

to LFieldStorage-1
  ask patches with [pcolor = 64.2]                                     ;; ask the fields at the right side of the river
  [
    set CurrentStorage (CurrentStorage + count RiverVolumes-here)
    sprout-WaterVolumes (count RiverVolumes-here)
    ask WaterVolumes-here
    [
      set color 97
      set size 0.8
      set heading 0
    ]
    ask RiverVolumes-here [die]
  ]
end

to LFieldStorageOverFlow-1
  ask patches with [pcolor = 64.2]                                   ;; ask the one of the fields which used to store the irrigation water
  [
    if CurrentStorage > FirstStorage                                                       ;; if the current storage exceeds the maximum storage
    [
      ask n-of (CurrentStorage - FirstStorage) WaterVolumes-here [die]                ;; ask the extra storage volumes to die (so they go out the system)
      set CurrentStorage FirstStorage                                                      ;; set current storage to the FirsIrrigationDemand
    ]
  ]
end

to RCropGrowth-1
  ask patches with [pcolor = 22.6]
  [
    if pxcor > 20 and ([CurrentStorage] of patch (pxcor - 1) pycor) = FirstStorage
    [
      sprout-Crops 1
      [
        set shape "plant"
        set size 0.1
        set color green
      ]
    ]
  ]
end

to LCropGrowth-1
  ask patches with [pcolor = 22.6]
  [
    if pxcor < 16 and ([CurrentStorage] of patch (pxcor + 1) pycor) = FirstStorage
    [
      sprout-Crops 1
      [
        set shape "plant"
        set size 0.1
        set color green
      ]
    ]
  ]
end

to DeathOfFirstWaterVolumes
  ask patches with [pcolor = 64.2 and pxcor > 20 and pycor = 1]
  [
    if any? Crops-on patch 36 1
    [
      ask WaterVolumes-here [die]
    ]
  ]

  ask patches with [pcolor = 64.2 and pxcor < 16  and pycor = 1]
  [
    if any? Crops-on patch 0 1
    [
      ask WaterVolumes-here [die]
    ]
  ]
end

to SecondIrrigation                                                                             ;; means flow the water to canals
  ifelse [CurrentStorage] of patch 35 1 < SecondStorage
  [
    move-to-right-canal1-2
    RGateCapacity-2
    RGateFlow1-2
    RFieldStorage-2
    RFieldStorageOverFlow-2
  ]
  [
    ifelse [CurrentStorage] of patch 1 1 < SecondStorage
    [
      move-to-left-canal1-2
      LGateCapacity-2
      LGateFlow1-2
      LFieldStorage-2
      LFieldStorageOverFlow-2
    ]
    [
      ask patches with [pycor = 0]
      [
        if any? RiverVolumes-here
        [
          ask RiverVolumes [die]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
end

to move-to-right-canal1-2
  ask patches with [pcolor = 95.1]
  [
    if pxcor = 18 and pycor = 0
    [
      ask n-of QgateMaxFixed1 RiverVolumes-here
      [
        lt 90
        fd 1
      ]
    ]
  ]
end

to RGateCapacity-2
  ask patches with [pcolor = 48.8]                                                      ;; gates at the right side of the river
  [
    ifelse pxcor = 19
    [
      set QgateMaxR1 QgateMaxFixed1                                                     ;; set the capacity of the first right gate is QgateMaxFixed1
    ]
    [
      set QgateMaxR QgateMaxFixed
    ]
  ]
end

to RGateFlow1-2
  ask patches with [pcolor = 48.8 and pycor = 0]                               ;; gates at the right side of the river
  [
    ifelse pxcor = 19
    [
      ask n-of QgateMaxFixed1 RiverVolumes-here [fd 1]
    ]
    [
      ifelse CurrentStorage < SecondStorage
      [
        ifelse (count RiverVolumes-here - QgateMaxR) > 0
        [
          ask n-of QgateMaxFixed RiverVolumes-here [lt 90]
        ]
        [
          ask n-of (count RiverVolumes-here) RiverVolumes-here [lt 90]
        ]
      ]
      [
      ]
    ]
  ]
end

to RFieldStorage-2
  ask patches with [pcolor = 64.2]                                     ;; ask the fields at the right side of the river
  [
    set CurrentStorage (CurrentStorage + count RiverVolumes-here)
    sprout-WaterVolumes (count RiverVolumes-here)
    ask WaterVolumes-here
    [
      set color 97
      set size 0.8
      set heading 0
    ]
    ask RiverVolumes-here [die]
  ]
end

to RFieldStorageOverFlow-2
  ask patches with [pcolor = 64.2]
  [
    if CurrentStorage > SecondStorage                                                       ;; if the current storage exceeds the maximum storage
    [
      ask n-of (CurrentStorage - SecondStorage) WaterVolumes-here [die]                ;; ask the extra storage volumes to die (so they go out the system)
      set CurrentStorage SecondStorage
    ]
  ]
end

to move-to-left-canal1-2
  ask patches with [pcolor = 95.1]
  [
    if pxcor = 18 and pycor = 0
    [
        ask n-of QgateMaxFixed1 RiverVolumes-here
        [
          rt 90
          fd 1
        ]
    ]
  ]
end

to LGateCapacity-2
  ask patches with [ pcolor = 47.4]                                                     ;; gates at the left side of the river
  [
    ifelse pxcor = 17
    [
      set QgateMaxL1 QgateMaxFixed1                                                     ;; set the capacity of the first right gate is QgateMaxFixed1
    ]
    [
      set QgateMaxL QgateMaxFixed
    ]
  ]
end

to LGateFlow1-2
  ask patches with [pcolor = 47.4 and pycor = 14]                               ;; gates at the left side of the river
  [
    ifelse pxcor = 17
    [
      ask n-of QgateMaxFixed1 RiverVolumes-here [fd 1]
    ]
    [
      ifelse CurrentStorage < SecondStorage
      [
        ifelse (count RiverVolumes-here - QgateMaxL) > 0
        [
          ask n-of QgateMaxFixed RiverVolumes-here [rt 90]
        ]
        [
          ask n-of (count RiverVolumes-here) RiverVolumes-here [rt 90]
        ]
      ]
      [
      ]
    ]
  ]
end

to LFieldStorage-2
  ask patches with [pcolor = 64.2]                                     ;; ask the fields at the right side of the river
  [
    set CurrentStorage (CurrentStorage + count RiverVolumes-here)
    sprout-WaterVolumes (count RiverVolumes-here)
    ask WaterVolumes-here
    [
      set color 97
      set size 0.8
      set heading 0
    ]
    ask RiverVolumes-here [die]
  ]
end

to LFieldStorageOverFlow-2
  ask patches with [pcolor = 64.2]
  [
    if CurrentStorage > SecondStorage                                                       ;; if the current storage exceeds the maximum storage
    [
      ask n-of (CurrentStorage - SecondStorage) WaterVolumes-here [die]                ;; ask the extra storage volumes to die (so they go out the system)
      set CurrentStorage SecondStorage
    ]
  ]
end

to RCropGrowth-2
  ask patches with [pcolor = 22.6]
  [
    if pxcor > 20 and ([CurrentStorage] of patch (pxcor - 1) pycor) = FirstStorage
    [
      sprout-Crops 1
      [
        set shape "plant"
        set size 0.2
        set color green
      ]
    ]
  ]
end

to LCropGrowth-2
  ask patches with [pcolor = 22.6]
  [
    if pxcor < 16 and ([CurrentStorage] of patch (pxcor + 1) pycor) = FirstStorage
    [
      sprout-Crops 1
      [
        set shape "plant"
        set size 0.2
        set color green
      ]
    ]
  ]
end

to DeathOfSecondWaterVolumes
  ask patches with [pcolor = 64.2 and pxcor > 20 and pycor = 1]
  [
    if any? Crops-on patch 36 1
    [
      ask WaterVolumes-here [die]
    ]
  ]

  ask patches with [pcolor = 64.2 and pxcor < 16  and pycor = 1]
  [
    if any? Crops-on patch 0 1
    [
      ask WaterVolumes-here [die]
    ]
  ]
end

to set-label
  ask patches with [pcolor = 64.2 or pcolor = 98.4 or pcolor = 47.4 or pcolor = 48.8 or pcolor = 94.5 or pcolor = 44.9 or pcolor = 95.1]
  [
    ifelse (count turtles-here) > 0
    [
      set plabel (count turtles-here)
      set plabel-color black
    ]
    [set plabel ""]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Please add the relevant NetLogo code from your model to your question.  It's nearly impossible for people to help without seeing the code.

Comment: You may want to use `show` to make your model generate additional output as it runs, in order to help you get insight into what is going on in your own code. (`set label` is also useful for this.)

Comment: Hi, Seth. Thanks for your reply. To use `show`, do you mean I can find the problem with the output? I used `set label` in the code, but nothing changed on the patches, I mean the patches do not show any number.

Comment: Hi, Jasper. Thanks for your reply. I added the code now. Could you please have a look? As the initial code is too complex, I simplified some un-related procedures.

Comment: Yes, `show` and `set label` are useful tools for investigation. They allow you to see what your code is doing.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestions, Seth! I will try to control these primitives.

Answer (score 2):

So I am going to take a guess here as, without your true setup procedure, there is no way for us to run the model. (We'd also need the values of your interface variables.) But the first line of `SecondProcedure` is

```
ifelse [CurrentStorage] of patch 35 15 < SecondStorage
```

Your `setup` or perhaps just using the NetLogo default likely initialized the `CurrentStorage` of this patch to zero.  Is it possible that in your first procedure this patch's `CurrentStorage` was filled to a level greater than or equal to `SecondStorage`, and the same for that of patch 1 15?  If so, your `SecondProcedure` will likely not give you the result you want.  You can check this (as Seth suggested) by putting a

```
show [CurrentStorage] of patch 35 15
```

before the `ifelse` to see what in fact its value is.  If I'm correct, it's not what you expect it should be and you'll need to reinitialize this and likely some other variables between your first and second period.

The `show` command is invaluable is debugging.  I suggest you use it liberally!

Comment: use `if ticks = 29`, not `if time = 29`. Your variable time is `mod` 24 so will never have a value of 29

Comment: Sorry for the writing error. It is the day, not time. I changed the statement as below: Dear Charles, you are totally correct and thanks for your suggestions. It's really helpful. I put `show` in the command center, it showed the [CurrentStorage] of each patch is still the maximum storage of the FirstProcedure. This could be the reason why the model cannot run in the SecondProcedure. I added the code ` if day = 29 [ask patches with [color = 64.2] [set CurrentStorage 0]]`but the result is the same. Could you please tell me how to reinitialize the patches' variables? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What does not work?  Are the CurrentStorage values not being reset to zero, or they are, but the model still fails to run as you expect?  And, don't you want to reset your variables on day 30?  And finally, are you sure that the patches in question have that pcolor?  Sprinkle some "show" statements around in the code of SecondProcedure to see how you are moving through it.

Comment: After I added the code` if day = 29 [ask patches with [color = 64.2] [set CurrentStorage 0]]` between the two procedures, the command center showed the [CurrentStorage] of the patches still the maximum storage in FirstProcedue, not to zero. From day 30, I set the patches have the new maximum storage and the turtles move to the patches, however, nothing happened during this period (the tick counter runs but the turtles don't move to the patches) and the CurrentStorage of each patch is still the maximum storage in FirstProcedure. I am sure the patches have such a pcolor.

Comment: So, now I am confused.  in the code you provided, day goes from 1 to 7, it will never equal 29, let alone be >= 31, let alone reach 30.

Comment: I am really sorry for the mistake. I set a weekly time scale before, and later I changed the time scale to daily. It was my fault I did not revise the code. I upload the new code now. Could you please have a look?

Comment: This question seems to have been answered over on Netlogo-users.

Comment: Yes. It solved based on your first answer here. Thank you very much, Charles!